# Python selenium with chrome webdriver - change user agent

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

I am running some code with selenium using python, and I figured out that I need to dynamically change the UserAgent after I already created the webdriver. Any advice if it is possible and how this could be done? Just to highlight - I want to change it on the fly, after almost each GET or POST request I send

Comment: It's possible with Firefox by calling "execute_script" on the "chrome" context and by overriding the header with `browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`. It's also possible with Chrome, but it requires to build an extension.

Comment: To change the header on the fly with a web extension: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with creating a new driver and copy all the necessary attributes from the old driver except the user agent.